# Rails do something and redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

is there a way to execute code and then redirect inside the routes-file like this:

```
get 'cache/clear' => Proc.new { Rails.cache.clear && redirect('/') }
```

I just really don't want to create a controller for this particular action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.  See here:  http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing

```
match "/foo", :to => proc {|env| [200, {}, ["Hello world"]] }
```

or, more specifically for your case

```
match "cache/clear", :to => redirect {Rails.cache.clear && '/'}
```

Comment: Were exactly (Without building a Sinatra app)?

Comment: Sorry, see edit.  I'm not 100% sure that works with a redirect though.

Comment: Yep. Works. I found this solution too, but anyway thanks! - `get 'cache/clear' => redirect { Rails.cache.clear; '/' }`